# Why running Python code in Rstudio gives redundant text?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, reticulate

I am running the following python code in R-notebook:

````
```{r}
library(reticulate)
```

```{python}
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()

```
````

It's strange because besides a plot, there is a text result.

> [image]
>   [image]

Could you please explain the reason for this phenomena?

Comment: It seems like RStudio is running the Python code in some sort of REPL

Comment: What happens if you use \`\`\`{python, include=FALSE}\`\`\`?

Comment: It still runs but returns nothing @r2evans.

Comment: It should still plot (per knitr's documentation), so that's different. There might be other [chunk arguments](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#code-evaluation) that would inform this, have you tried any of the others? (I don't know that the affect python the same way they affect R, that might be a difference. I'm not familiar with python plotting, but can you capture the return values of each of your `plt.*` calls so that python doesn't try to print something to the console?)

Comment: Thank you for your reference @r2evans! I will look at it later :)

Comment: Well this is a behaviour of `matplotlib`.  Even in python itself, unless you save the output to a given variable, there will be text printed on your console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is @Onyambu comment. I post it here to remove my question from unanswered list.

> Well this is a behaviour of `matplotlib`. Even in python itself, unless you save the output to a given variable, there will be text printed on your console